# Compiling Ruby on Mac 10.8 first time

Tags: ruby, macos, compilation

I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0 on my Mac running 10.8.3, and on the Ruby website it says to compile the source code. I downloaded the folder, but it has a bunch of code files in it, what do they mean by 'compile' ? I am stuck and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

try this i think it is from basic to install rails on OSX 10.8

http://www.rackspace.com/blog/installing-rails-an-a-mac/

http://newbieonruby.com/installing-ruby-and-rails-on-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend skipping all that trouble and checking out http://railsinstaller.org/#osx